# Boost-Asio , multi-thread tcp server

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm not able to succeed about boost-asio multithread program.

Since there is not any good example or documentation about this, 
I want your help :)

Simply, I think this code do listen, but when I want to 'cout' buffer data, 
it does not print anything or listening once and stopped.

My code is:

```
void Worker::startThread(int clientNumber) {
     cout << "listening: "<< clients[clientNumber]->port << endl;
     boost::asio::io_service io_service;
     tcp::acceptor acc(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),portNumber[clientNumber]));
     socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
     acc.accept(*sock);
     try
     {
     for (;;) {
        char data[max_length];
        boost::system::error_code error;
         cout << "message?" << endl;
        size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
         cout << "message :)" << endl;
        cout << data << endl;
        if(error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
        else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

     }
     }
     catch (std::exception& e)
     {
         std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
     }
}
void Worker::start() {
     cout << "Starting thread server" << endl;
     for(int i=0; i<clients.size(); i++) {
         boost::thread t(boost::bind(&Worker::startThread, this, i));
     }

     for(;;);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't looked at the documentation very long if you don't see the [multi-threaded examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

> ### HTTP Server 3
>
> An HTTP server using a single
>   io_service and a thread pool calling
>   io_service::run().

---

> ### HTTP Server 2
>
> An HTTP server using an
>   io_service-per-CPU design.

Keep in mind these examples use asynchronous methods, which is where the Boost.Asio library really shines.

Answer (score 4):

You've basically copied the [Blocking TCP Echo Server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp) example yet you're unable to find a good example or documentation?

Anyway, I see some problems with your code:

- Your saying your listening on `clients[clientNumber]->port` but the actual port you're listening on is `portNumber[clientNumber]`;
- You need to zero-terminate your `data` after `read_some` and before printing it;
- As soon as the `error == boost::asio::error::eof` condition is true (the client disconnected) the thread will exit and therefore you'll not be able to (re)connect another client on that port;
- You're only accepting the first connection / client, any other clients connecting on the same port will not have their messages handled in any way.

Comment: thanks for replies, clients[clientNumber]->port and portNumber[clientNumber] have same values. I meant that while listening, I can get message from clients once from related port, therefore, further messages can not delivered by clients. [Exception: Connection Refused]

Comment: I have already removed that line, but in that case,instead of message (comes from every 1 minutes) some garbage characters comes every ~0.5sec

Comment: Is you example complete? By the looks of it you're not running the io_service?

Comment: @Andre you don't need to run the io_service when exclusively using synchronous methods.

Comment: @darkalive: think about what are the TCP operations on the server side (especially the listen & accept part), what sockets are created during those operations, when the original example created threads, why the example used a `shared_ptr` to hold `sock` although it is local variable...